# Issue in predicate function in wait in thread C++

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex, wait, condition-variable

I am trying to put the condition inside a function but it is throwing confusing compile time error . While if I write it in lambda function  like this []{ retur i == k;} it is showing k is unidentified . Can anybody tell How to solve this problem .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;
condition_variable cv;
mutex m;
int i;
bool check_func(int i,int k)
{
    return i == k;
}
void print(int k)
{
   unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
   cv.wait(lk,check_func(i,k));            // Line 33
   cout<<"Thread no. "<<this_thread::get_id()<<" parameter "<<k<<"\n";
   i++;
   return;
}
int main() 
{
    thread threads[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       threads[i] = thread(print,i);
    for(auto &t : threads)
       t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

## Compiler Error:

```
In file included from 6:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/condition_variable: In instantiation of 'void std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&, _Predicate) [with _Predicate = bool]':
33:30:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/condition_variable:97:14: error: '__p' cannot be used as a function
  while (!__p())
              ^
```

Answer (score 3):

[`wait()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) takes a predicate, which is a *callable* unary function returning bool. `wait()` uses that predicate like so:

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

`check_func(i,k)` is a `bool`. It's not callable and it's a *constant* - which defeats the purpose. You're waiting on something that can change. You need to wrap it in something that can be repeatedly callable - like a lambda:

```
   cv.wait(lk, [&]{ return check_func(i,k); });
```

Comment: To clarify a bit, it's not really a constant -- it's an expression that evaluates to a boolean value, and that value is what's being passed to `wait` (not the function itself).

Comment: I believe there should be a return keyword before check_func . After that it is not causing any compile time error . But after that it is getting hanged and causing time limit exceed and come out without printing anything ?

Comment: @user Well, all your threads are waiting for something to happen that will never happen. That's a programming logic error.